# Request With Alamofire but getting error - code: -1202

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, server, alamofire

I want my app does not check SSL certificate when request to server
what should I do ?

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “domain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690302/certificate-for-this-server-is-invalid

Comment: @DharmeshKheni didn't work