# NativeScript running iOS fails on local server using HTTPS

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ssl-certificate, nativescript

I'm having issues with NativeScript running iOS (either simulated or physical) communicating with my local server (either running on linux or on the same test deployment running on my MacBook) due to SSL issues. From the searching I've already done this is due to the app transport security blocking the request as it's an untrusted SSL connection. I've modified the file app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist to add the lines

```
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>`
```

but it is still failing. The inner exception states

`Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.40” which could put your confidential information at risk.`

These lines should resolve the issue as it allows for untrusted communication. It seems that they're getting ignored. Any ideas why this might be failing?

Here's the full stack trace...

```
`
(qrmobileapp) Created Activity ID: 0x96907, Description: Loading Preferences From System CFPrefsD
(CFNetwork) Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
(CFNetwork) Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
(CFNetwork) Creating default cookie storage with process/bundle identifier
(CFNetwork) TIC Enabling TLS [1:0x60400016a800]
(CFNetwork) TIC TCP Conn Start [1:0x60400016a800]
(CFNetwork) Task <D90CBCBA-DFC6-4299-AE58-50B49901D304>.<1> setting up Connection 1
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] [1 192.168.0.40:44321 stream, pid: 85993, url: https://192.168.0.40:44321/api/appuser/test, tls] start
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [1:0x60400016a800]: 1, Pending(0)
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [1:0x60400016a800]: 2, Pending(0)
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [1:0x60400016a800]: 11, Pending(0)
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [1:0x60400016a800]: 12, Pending(0)
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [1:0x60400016a800]: 14, Pending(0)
(qrmobileapp) Created Activity ID: 0x96908, Description: SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
(Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf AnchorTrusted SSLHostname]
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Trust Result [1:0x60400016a800]: 2
(CFNetwork) TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x60400016a800]: 3:0
(CFNetwork) TIC TCP Conn Cancel [1:0x60400016a800]
(CFNetwork) NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
(CFNetwork) Task <D90CBCBA-DFC6-4299-AE58-50B49901D304>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])
(CFNetwork) Task <D90CBCBA-DFC6-4299-AE58-50B49901D304>.<1> finished with error - code: -1202
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] [1 192.168.0.40:44321 stream, pid: 85993, url: https://192.168.0.40:44321/api/appuser/test, tls] cancelled. Events:
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] 0.000s [1 D6B6A870-33A7-422C-B22F-782F5A933AAD 192.168.0.40:44321 socket-flow] path:start
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] 0.000s [1 D6B6A870-33A7-422C-B22F-782F5A933AAD 192.168.0.40:44321 socket-flow] path:satisfied
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] 0.010s [1 D6B6A870-33A7-422C-B22F-782F5A933AAD 192.168.0.40:44321 socket-flow] flow:start_connect
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] 0.014s [1 D6B6A870-33A7-422C-B22F-782F5A933AAD 192.168.0.40:44321 socket-flow] flow:finish_transport
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] 0.056s [1] path:cancel
(CFNetwork) TIC TCP Conn Destroyed [1:0x60400016a800]
(qrmobileapp) Created Activity ID: 0x96909, Description: SecTrustReportTLSAnalytics
(CFNetwork) TIC Enabling TLS [2:0x60c00016a380]
(CFNetwork) TIC TCP Conn Start [2:0x60c00016a380]
(CFNetwork) Task <A96EE6D0-30B8-4950-AC4C-DC1F9BD02E8F>.<2> setting up Connection 2
(libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:] [2 192.168.0.40:44321 stream, pid: 85993, url: https://192.168.0.40:44321/api/appuser/getToken, tls] start
(qrmobileapp) Created Activity ID: 0x9690a, Description: send control actions
(CFNetwork) TIC TLS Event [2:0x60c00016a380]: 1, Pending(0)
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1682:24: ERROR {
"headers": {
"normalizedNames": {},
"lazyUpdate": null,
"headers": {}
},
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url": null,
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
"error": {
"line": 1298,
"column": 38,
"sourceURL": "file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js",
"originalStack": "ZoneAwareError@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:38\nfile:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/http/http-request/http-request.js:87:37\nUIApplicationMain@[native code]\nstart@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:272:26\nrun@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:300:10\nbootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:160:26\nbootstrapApp@fil`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/45299526/4936697